# Timestamp datatype in MYSQL DB

Tags: mysql, datetime

I asked my freelancer to convert the date in my raw data (Bulletin Date : 18/09/2015) to be as 18-sep-2015

But later i found out that the application which will read this DB (using ODBC) requires date to be a TIMESTAMP format. (Code in PHP)

```
$text = file_get_contents($name);
$date = getbetween($text, "Bulletin Date : ", "\n");
$date = substr($date, 0, 11);
$date = explode("/", $date);
$date = $date[0] . "-" . $date[1] . "-" . $date[2];
$date1 = mktime(0, 0, 0, $date[1], $date[0], $date[2]);
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date1);
```

Also, in my MySQL DB i have set the DATE field with the datatype :TIMESTAMP

Now when i load data in my DB using the above code i get "1970-01-01 01:00:00"  for date field in all records.

Why is the date in DB messed up?

Comment: You say that you "load data in my DB using the above code". I am interpreting this to mean that you load data FROM the database with this code, when based on the code I would expect the code to load data from a file TO the database. Could you describe exactly what changes you have made and exactly where you are seeing the incorrect date fields?

Answer (score 0):

You never explicitly said that you are using PHP, but I assume that you are since you are using PHPMyAdmin and your code looks like PHP.

The answer to question 2 seems very easy. If you need the data in TIMESTAMP format, then I assume that means that you want the TIMESTAMP datatype in PHPMyAdmin.

To convert a date to that format, you could use

```php
$timestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes, $seconds, $month. $day, $year)
// If the date does not contain a time, set $hours, $minutes, and
// $seconds to zero:
// $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month. $day, $year)
$mysql_timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp)
```

See the documentation for the [TIMESTAMP datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) and the [date() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: I have implemented your suggestions, and based on the output I have updated the question. Can you please tell me why am i getting "1970-01-01 01:00:00" date for all records in DB?